# Ordering a list according to enum property of object

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a entity class 'Car' with number of properties including an Enum

```
public enum CarType 
{ BRANDNEW 
  ALMOSTNEW 
  OLD
}
```

When i get list of Car objects, i want to order the list with brand new cars on top, then almost new cars and old cars at the bottom. 
    I tried ordering with car name which works out pretty fine

`CarsList = new ObservableCollection<Car>(CarViewModel.OrderBy(item => item.Name))`

But i want to order the list according to the enum type.

I tried adding `int` value to the enum type

```
public enum CarType 
{ BRANDNEW = 1
  ALMOSTNEW = 2
  OLD = 3
} 

CarsList = new ObservableCollection<Car>(CarViewModel.OrderBy(item => item.CarType))
```

But didn't work.

Comment: `But didn't work` is not a technical description of a problem, what didn't work about it, it didn't change, it was backwards, it was random?

Comment: @MichaelRandall It was random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is elsewhere as there is nothing seemingly wrong with your `OrderBy`, (as seen by this verifiable minimal example)

```
public enum CarType
{
    BRANDNEW = 1,
    ALMOSTNEW = 2,
    OLD = 3
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<CarType>{CarType.ALMOSTNEW, CarType.OLD, CarType.BRANDNEW};
    var asd = list.OrderBy(item => item);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", asd));
}
```

**Output**

```
BRANDNEW
ALMOSTNEW
OLD
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/7qdALA)

The most likely cause of your problem, is that you are not reassigning or updating the UI with the results of your query.

```
CarsList = new ObservableCollection<Car>(CarViewModel.OrderBy(item => item.CarType))
```

You can prove the order by is working by the following, check the results by looking at your output window

```
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", CarsList ));
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for the help. The problem was, i was actually ordering the list before every property of the object was initialised, hence the random behaviour.

Comment: Nice explanation +1